# How to skip undefined values in gnu matrix plot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the following dataset by `matrix with image` in gnuplot:

ifile.txt

```
1 2 3 3 ? 4
2 ? 4 3 4 ?
3 4 5 3 5 3
```

I use the command

```
plot 'ifile.txt' matrix with image
```

It is plotting the `?` as 0 value, while I would like to the skip it as blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer for this. I need to set the missing values in the script as:

```
 set datafile missing "?"
```